# Kotlin compose, can't type into textfields using viewModel

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm just starting my journey into android using kotlin compose after learning python for the last few years. So it's still very strange and new to me at the moment.

I've started with the login/registration screens, and i'm using viewModel to talk to the composables. However the below code doesn't let me type into any of the textfields. And in addition to that even clicking the "login" button with nothing in the text fields should in theory send me a toast message, but it doesn't do that either. So i'm thinking there is a issue with the way the LoginViewModel is set up but after several days of trying to understand and work it out myself i'm still stuck due to my lack of knowledge in kotlin.

Could someone please take a look and see if you can tell where i might be going wrong please ?

i've taken snippets of the code so i don't paste too much into here. I think it should be enough code to understand what i have.

Oh and should maybe mention, i'm on ubuntu running electric eel version of android studio and the same issue happens regardless if i runthe app on my phone or inthe emulator.

```
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.drawable.Icon
import android.media.Image
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Surface
import com.ftc.nomadicworker.R
import org.w3c.dom.Text

/*
LoginScreen.kt file
This holds the composables that make up the signin and signup screens
*/

@Composable
fun LoginScreen(
    loginViewModel: LoginViewModel? = null,
    onNavToHomePage: () -> Unit,
    onNavToSignUpPage: () -> Unit,
) {
    val loginUiState = loginViewModel?.loginUiState
    println("LoginScreen: loginUiState: $loginUiState")
    val isError = loginUiState?.loginError != null
    val context = LocalContext.current

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    ) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground),
            contentDescription = "Logo",
            modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
        )
        Text(
            text = "Login",
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h4,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Black,
            color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary
        )

        if (isError) {
            Text(
                text = loginUiState?.loginError ?: "unknown error",
                color = Color.Red,
            )
        }

        OutlinedTextField(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(16.dp),
            value = loginUiState?.userName ?: "",
            onValueChange = { loginViewModel?.onUserNameChange(it) },
            leadingIcon = {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Default.Person,
                    contentDescription = null,
                )
            },
            label = {
                Text(text = "Email")
            },
            isError = isError
        )
        OutlinedTextField(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(16.dp),
            value = loginUiState?.password ?: "",
            onValueChange = { loginViewModel?.onPasswordNameChange(it) },
            leadingIcon = {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Default.Lock,
                    contentDescription = null,
                )
            },
            label = {
                Text(text = "Password")
            },
            visualTransformation = PasswordVisualTransformation(),
            isError = isError
        )

        Button(onClick = { loginViewModel?.loginUser(context) }) {
            Text(text = "Sign In")
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(16.dp))

        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        ) {
            Text(text = "Don't have an Account?")
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(8.dp))
            TextButton(onClick = { onNavToSignUpPage.invoke() }) {
                Text(text = "SignUp")
            }


        }

        if (loginUiState?.isLoading == true) {
            CircularProgressIndicator()
        }

        LaunchedEffect(key1 = loginViewModel?.hasUserBeenLoggedIn) {
            if (loginViewModel?.hasUserBeenLoggedIn == true) {
                onNavToHomePage.invoke()
            }
        }


    }


}
....

/*
LoginViewModel.kt file

This is the associated viewModel for the above login screens.
*/


class LoginViewModel(
    private val repository: AuthRepository = AuthRepository(),
) : ViewModel() {
    val currentUser = repository.currentUser

    val hasUserBeenLoggedIn: Boolean
        get() = repository.hasUserBeenLoggedIn()

    // These next two don't work as it tells me off for
    // @Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function
    // Which i think is ok cause i dont need to remeber the login fields anyway ?
    //val loginUiState = remember { mutableStateOf(LoginUiState()) }
    //var loginUiState by remember { mutableStateOf(LoginUiState()) }

    // This seems to not give a error
    var loginUiState by mutableStateOf(LoginUiState())
        private set


    fun onUserNameChange(userName: String) {
        println("onUserNameChange: $userName")
        loginUiState = loginUiState.copy(userName = userName)
    }

    fun onPasswordNameChange(password: String) {
        loginUiState = loginUiState.copy(password = password)
    }

    fun onUserNameChangeSignup(userName: String) {
        loginUiState = loginUiState.copy(userNameSignUp = userName)
    }

    fun onPasswordChangeSignup(password: String) {
        loginUiState = loginUiState.copy(passwordSignUp = password)
    }

    fun onConfirmPasswordChange(password: String) {
        loginUiState = loginUiState.copy(confirmPasswordSignUp = password)
    }

    private fun validateLoginForm() =
        loginUiState.userName.isNotBlank() &&
                loginUiState.password.isNotBlank()

    private fun validateSignupForm() =
        loginUiState.userNameSignUp.isNotBlank() &&
                loginUiState.passwordSignUp.isNotBlank() &&
                loginUiState.confirmPasswordSignUp.isNotBlank()


    fun createUser(context: Context) = viewModelScope.launch {
        try {
            if (!validateSignupForm()) {
                throw IllegalArgumentException("Email and password can not be empty")
            }
            loginUiState = loginUiState.copy(isLoading = true)
            if (loginUiState.passwordSignUp !=
                loginUiState.confirmPasswordSignUp
            ) {
                throw IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Password do not match"
                )
            }
            loginUiState = loginUiState.copy(signUpError = null)
            repository.createUser(
                loginUiState.userNameSignUp,
                loginUiState.passwordSignUp
            ) { isSuccessful ->
                loginUiState = if (isSuccessful) {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        context,
                        "success Login",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                    loginUiState.copy(isSuccessLogin = true)
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        context,
                        "Failed Login",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                    loginUiState.copy(isSuccessLogin = false)
                }

            }


        } catch (e: Exception) {
            loginUiState = loginUiState.copy(signUpError = e.localizedMessage)
            e.printStackTrace()
        } finally {
            loginUiState = loginUiState.copy(isLoading = false)
        }


    }

    fun loginUser(context: Context) = viewModelScope.launch {
        try {
            if (!validateLoginForm()) {
                throw IllegalArgumentException("email and password can not be empty")
            }
            loginUiState = loginUiState.copy(isLoading = true)
            loginUiState = loginUiState.copy(loginError = null)
            repository.login(
                loginUiState.userName,
                loginUiState.password
            ) { isSuccessful ->
                loginUiState = if (isSuccessful) {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        context,
                        "success Login",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                    loginUiState.copy(isSuccessLogin = true)
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        context,
                        "Failed Login",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                    loginUiState.copy(isSuccessLogin = false)
                }

            }


        } catch (e: Exception) {
            loginUiState = loginUiState.copy(loginError = e.localizedMessage)
            e.printStackTrace()
        } finally {
            loginUiState = loginUiState.copy(isLoading = false)
        }


    }


}

data class LoginUiState(
    val userName: String = "",
    val password: String = "",
    val userNameSignUp: String = "",
    val passwordSignUp: String = "",
    val confirmPasswordSignUp: String = "",
    val isLoading: Boolean = false,
    val isSuccessLogin: Boolean = false,
    val signUpError: String? = null,
    val loginError: String? = null,
)


/* MainActivity.kt

*/


class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    //private val loginViewModel: LoginViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyAndroidAppTheme {
                val loginViewModel = viewModel(modelClass = LoginViewModel::class.java)
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {
                    Navigation(loginViewModel = loginViewModel)

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer posted below has fixed your problem, but I'll suggest that you store variables inside a `remember {}` to prevent them from getting recomposed every time a composable recomposes. e.g: isError variable, every time the composable is recomposed , that statement is checked every time

Comment: @MAshhal, for something as trivial as a null check, I don't think it makes sense to remember it. The mechanism that stores and then restores your variable on each recomposition is almost certainly more overhead than the null-check. It has to stash the value in a collection and then restore it from that collection. Keep in mind, for a computed value like this, you would also have to key the `remember` call on the state it depends on, so it's even more overhead than a typical `remember` call. Even if it isn't, the difference would be insignificant, so no need to make the code more convoluted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you pass a null value for your ViewModel into this Composable? It doesn’t make sense that it even is a nullable property. You should declare it like

```
loginViewModel: LoginViewModel = viewModel()
```

so it isn’t nullable and you don’t even have to pass it in. Still good practice to keep it as a function parameter for the sake of unit testing.

All those ?. calls do nothing if it’s null. That’s a sign that the parameter shouldn’t be nullable at all. Only use ?. when your code expects something to sometimes be null and can still be useful without it.

Comment: You're a legend, been bursting blood vessels trying to work that out. :) You are correct, once i changed null to viewModel(), got rid of the .?'s and then removed all the elvis operators it came to life. it works yayyy i'm sooo happy now.

I'm off to do some more research on it so i dont get caught out again. Thanks. appreciate it

Comment: @Lazza I forgot to mention. I noticed you had some comments in there that expressed surprise that you couldn't use `remember` in your ViewModel. That's because it doesn't make sense to use `remember` outside a Composable. `remember` makes a variable maintain its value each time a Composition is recomposed, but a ViewModel isn't a Composition. Your whole ViewModel instance is remembered between compositions, but that's through a different mechanism that keeps ViewModels stored for reuse for as long as their associated Activity or Fragment is in the stack.

Comment: When you call `viewModel()`, under the hood it is checking if an instance of your ViewModel is already attached to the current Fragment or Activity, and returns the existing instance. Otherwise, it instantiates an instance, which will subsequently be the one returned on further calls to `viewModel()`.

Comment: Ahh thanks for that. I was following tutorials on the android developer page and they mentioned those three ways to remember something and was confused why none of them worked for me. Now I know :)